# How to achieve this design by html and css with flex property or something else

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make Todo list and I add div for each task. So I have two span tag and two buttons but I have not idea how to implement this. I think flex property will help and i tried but can't achieve

[image: pointer is hover on div then button will displayed]

can you suggest any detailed video on flex property?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what does it look like?

Comment: blue div, display:flex; width: 100%; first span width:10%; second span width:70%; buttons width :10%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may work for you.

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
}
.box-1{
  background-color: green;
}
.box-2{
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="box-1">Your Logo Text</span>
  <span class="box-2"></span>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ws23hb46/

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
  xxx
  </div>
   <div class="foo">
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
   <div>
    <button>
    a
    </button>
  </div>
   <div>
  <button>
    b
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;  // direction is row by default
  justify-content:space-between;
  
}

.container > div {
  padding:1em;
  margin:1em;
  background-color:grey;
}

.foo { 
  flex:1 0 100%; // 1 = take the remaining space (same as flex-grow:1;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with btn's

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style>
    
        .div1{
           display: flex;
           justify-content: space-between;
           padding: 20px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="div1">
        <div style="width:20%";>
           <span>some text</span>
       </div>
       <div style="width:40%";>
           <span>some larger text column</span>
       </div>
       <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
    <button type="button"class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>    </div>

     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```